# Why does using Date.now() in condition create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, infinite-loop

I wanted to create a loop that could simulate a 5 second delay but ended up creating an infinite loop. I don't get why that works this way.

```js
let a = Date.now() + 5000;
while(Date.now() < a) {
    console.log(1);
}
```

What is wrong? a is a fixed value and isn't Date.now() supposed to get changed after every iteration?

I'm also wondering why setTimeout still works when the loop is infnite? Isn't it supposed to get executed only after the currently executing script is complete? Since this script is never complete why does setTimeout still get invoked?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    alert(2);
}, 2000);
let a = Date.now() + 5000;
while( Date.now() < a ) {
    console.log(1)
}
```

Comment: Your code will pile up millions of calls to `console.log()` over the course of those 5 seconds. That is not the way to delay execution in JavaScript, as you have apparently discovered.

Comment: Because at the end of a timeout the callback function runs; that’s its only job. An empty loop with output will crush your CPU, output buffer, and render loop.

Comment: It may look like an infinite loop, but actually the `while` loop will only run for 5 seconds and after that the browser will be stuck processing all those console logs, which is why it looks to you like it is executing forever

Comment: As for the `setTimeout` it can not be executed until the `while` loop is done, it may not be executed right after the while loop is done, because the browser may decide to spend processing time printing console logs instead

Comment: @DaveNewton That statement is wrong, it can not be executed at the end of the timeout because javascript can not run code in parallel and in his code he will loop much longer than the timeout. You're just going to confuse him like that

Comment: As a solution to this issue I would recommend just removing the `console.log` from your code. Then the `while` loop will run for 5 seconds, like you expect it to. Although that is going to freez your UI.

Comment: @zoran404 And yet it runs.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes it does run at some point, but not at the end of the timeout, which I think may confuse people not yet familiar with js, since in many other languages the code would actually run in parallel exactly at the end of the timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is not creating infinite loop. It will keep printing 1 until 5 seconds over. I tested it locally. But print is pretty fast, it looks like infinite loop. Scroll down and see at the end printing will be stopped. You can try same code by giving just 500 ms.

```js
let a = Date.now() + 500;
while(Date.now() < a) {
    console.log(1);
}
console.log("finished");
```

Now come to another question to understand why setTimeout worked, you have to understand internal working of Javascript. I will recommend this video [How JavaScript Works & Execution Context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvbzSrg0afE)

In JS, all functions which will execute are pushed to call stack for execution. In this case `console.log` method in while loop .

JS engine also has a callback queue which will have callback functions ready to be executed and there is event loop which always checks if call stack is empty. If yes, it will take the callback function from the callback queue and push it to the call stack for execution.
Here `setTimeout` function has a callback, once timer will expire this callback will be pushed to the callback queue.

Your while loop is just pushing `console.log` for execution one after another and it's getting executed in no time.
But as soon as there is a callback present in the callback queue and call stack is empty for a moment (means it's ready for another function to execute), event loop just push the callback for execution and removes from the queue. This process will be continued till all callbacks in the queue will be executed.
So callbacks have higher priority when it comes to execution.
You can try example with multiple `setTimeout` as well.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: *all functions which will execute are pushed to call stack for executed.* — this is not correct. Normal function calls are simple synchronous calls. Indeed, even the calls to `console.log()` in the OP are synchronous; what is *not* synchronous (varies between environments) is the *implementation* of `console.log()`, which may internally involve asynchronous operations to request that messages be logged somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy I agree that the implementaion of `console.log` varies between environments. Lets say console.log not uses call stack then any idea how js engine is executing it? Because it's also a function call how js will treat it?

Comment: A function call is a complicated thing, but it happens directly. A normal function call does not involve queuing up an action the way that a Promise `.then()` does or the way `setTimeout()` does. In terms of how that linked video describes it, it's still step-by-step synchronous single-threaded execution, but the "step" from the function call in an expression to the first statement of the function is a big step.

Comment: @pointy I agree normal function call doesn't need to be queued for execution. But still that normal function has to be executed somewhere and it should also have some execution context which again should be in call stack.

Comment: Yes, that is true: part of what happens when a function call starts is that a context is created. (Actually it's two contexts, one for the actual parameters and one for the function body.) And yes there is conceptually a stack of active functions.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to test the comments you're getting saying it's a 'console.log' problem - that the problem you're experiencing is because your pc is struggling to process all those log calls. I commented it out, and console.logged only after the loop finishes:

```js
let a = Date.now() + 5000;
while(Date.now() < a) {
    // console.log(1);
}

console.log('done');
```

It seems to work just fine, logs 'done' after 5 seconds.

Edit. After prompting from Pointy, I've accepted that it's probably a good idea to put a disclaimer here: nobody should be implementing this kind of loop as a way to wait for something.

Comment: This is technically correct, but nobody should be advised to run tight thread-blocking loops in JavaScript, in particular people who don't know _why_ they shouldn't run tight thread-blocking loops.

Comment: Commenting out the `console.log` from the loop is exactly what I suggested in the comments...

Comment: @Pointy this answer is not a SUGGESTION, this answer is a way of demonstrating a fact - the fact is, the loop is not an infinite loop, it stops exactly when it should stop.

Comment: @TKoL yea I get that, it's what I meant by "technically correct".

Comment: @Pointy I've added a disclaimer to my answer